# Math, something a bit complicated for me

Tags: math

so I have a math question, i need to use it in my code.
say this:

---

```
630 ---> 10000
125 ---> 1000
230 ---> ??
can anyone help me solve this?
with an explanation maybe...
```

---

Comment: This is neither a math nor a [programming](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question.

Comment: What are the numbers? That's some kind of riddle?

Comment: Im using it for programming..
so basically i need to set the sound for something using this: [link](https://gyazo.com/d2c19ece0eb9a108e67610fc218ead77)
the 1st point x it is on is 125, so i need 125 to be 1000 hz
and the last point x is 630, which i need to be 10000hz
so if when moved, the point became 176, how much would the hz be

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as OP states, it is a question of mathematics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like multiplication by 5 on the left translates to multiplication by 10 on the right, as 125*5=625. I'd guess that you do not want a linear but an exponential connection, something like

```
y=10^log5(x) = pow( 10, log(x)/log(5) )
             = x*pow( 2, log(x)/log(5) )
             = x*pow(x, log(2)/log(5) )
```